# Underfull \hbox and Underfull \vbox

Tags: warnings

I get the following couple of warnings when compiling my tex code. The `\hbox` warning is due to one of the articles I cite from my bibliography. What is the way to fix it?

```
 Underfull \hbox (badness 1997) in paragraph at lines 151--153
 []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Author X (year) Name of the article. Name of the journal
```

---

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [15])
[16]
```

Comment: Hard to help given so little information it is _always_ better to post complete (small) documents. The underfull hbox means tex had trouble breaking a line, you have the choice of ignoring it if you think it is good enough, or changing the line breaking options eg making it raggedright or \sloppy, but hard to say. Similarly the second one means that tex could not break the page in a acceptable way, you could do a forced \clearpage (which tells tex it is allowed to leave the page short) or use \raggedbottom (allow all pages to be short) or ignore the warning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you clarify what you mean by "Hard to help given so little information it is always better to post complete (small) documents"? Since it is only a warning, I do not understand how posting a small document will help. What other information should I post? I do not wish to reveal the name of the author and title of the publication from my bibliography and hence if I edit the author name and title to post here, the warning might also disappear.

Comment: You can fake a bibliography and other data with words of the same size. But if you just show a warning with _no_ indication of what caused the warning, it rather limits how we can advise altering the document to make the warning go.

Comment: I'm sure you have reasons, but I have to wonder why the name/article in the bibliography is secret.  Anyway, can you add discretionary hyphens in the words near where the line break occurs?  Maybe there are words in the title or journal title that TeX doesn't know how to handle properly.